# How do I a raise collection of quantum gates to the power N in Q-circuit?

Tags: qcircuit

I want to group a collection of gates and raise them to the power N. Attached is a minimal working example of what I'm trying to do--just missing the "to the power N" on the right parenthesis, i.e. I have ) but want )^N.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{qcircuit}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \[
    \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
    \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{U} & \gate{X} & \gate{Y} & \gate{X} & \gate{Y} & \gate{U^{\dagger}} & \meter  \qw \gategroup{1}{3}{1}{6}{.7em}{(} \gategroup{1}{3}{1}{6}{.7em}{)}
    }
    \]
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses in a `\gategroup` command are drawn using the XY-pic package. You can redefine the relevant command from XY-pic, which in this case is `\rparenthesized`, to include a superscript.

To make sure the superscript does not interfere in the size computations of the braces the superscript can be set inside of a `\smash` command, which prints the contents but does not reserve any space for it.

To make it a bit customizable you can define the superscript as a command which you can redefine before use. Of course it would be cleaner to use an argument but then you have to propagate that throughout the `qcircuit` and `xy` code which would involve changing a lot of code. In the MWE below I used `\gatesup` for the superscript content, which initially is empty (`{}`), so no superscript printed. The code added to `\rparenthesized` is

`\smash{\kern-4pt{}_\gatesup}`

which means "move 4pt to the left, then an empty root with `\gatesup` as subscript". Note that subscript is used here for a superscript, because of the positioning an actual superscript would be much too high. If you want to change the positioning or the font size of the superscript then you should modify this line - but note that you cannot increase or reduce the space used for the superscript easily as this involves modifying other parts of the `xy` code.

The contents of the superscript can be defined inside the `\Qcircuit` specification. Note that the definition must be global (`\gdef`) to take effect. You can redefine the macro afterwards to the empty group (`\def\gatesup{{}}` again) to 'switch off' the superscript for further right parentheses.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{qcircuit}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\xydef@\rparenthesized{\xy@@{\setboxz@h{%
 \A@=\X@c \advance\A@\R@c \B@=\Y@c \advance\B@-\D@c
 \setboxz@h{$\m@th\bracecr$}\dimen@ii=\dp\z@ \advance\A@-.5\wdz@
 \setboxz@h{$\m@th\bracec$}\dimen@=\dp\z@
 \ifdim\U@c<.5\dimen@ \U@c=.5\dimen@ \fi
 \ifdim\D@c<.5\dimen@ \advance\B@-.5\dimen@ \advance\B@\D@c \D@c=.5\dimen@ \fi
 \advance\U@c.6\p@ \advance\D@c.6\p@ \advance\B@-.6\p@
 \dimen@ii\U@c \advance\dimen@ii\D@c
 \kern\A@\raise\B@\vbox to \dimen@ii{%
 \nointerlineskip\hbox{$\m@th\braceul\smash{\kern-4pt{}_\gatesup}$}%
 \kern-.61\dimen@ \cleaders\copy\z@\vfil \kern-.61\dimen@
 \nointerlineskip\hbox{$\m@th\bracedl$}\kern\z@}}%
 \ht\z@=\z@ \dp\z@=\z@ \wd\z@=\z@ \boxz@}}
\makeatother

\def\gatesup{{}}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \[
    \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
    \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{U} & \gate{X} & \gate{Y} & \gate{X} & \gate{Y} & \gate{U^{\dagger}} & \meter  \qw \gategroup{1}{3}{1}{6}{.7em}{(} \gdef\gatesup{N}\gategroup{1}{3}{1}{6}{.7em}{)}
    }
    \]
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]